# Error in CREATE TABLE MYSQL : SYNTAX

Tags: mysql, web, database-administration

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pforum` 

( 
    pf_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    pf_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    pf_title varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    pf_ppost varchar(1000) NOT NULL, 
    pf_aud varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    pf_username varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    pf_date timestamp(14) NOT NULL, 
    pf_status  int(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (pr_id) 

    )  ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_reset`
( 
     pr_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     pr_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     pr_email varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
     pr_dob varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     pr_roll varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     pr_date timestamp(14) NOT NULL, 
     pr_status int(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (pr_id) ) ;
```

I have checked possible causes but I still get an error 1064 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pf_date timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
```

to

```
pf_date timestamp  NOT NULL,
```

AND

```
pr_date timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
```

to

```
pr_date timestamp  NOT NULL,
```

HEre is the correct one

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pforum` 

( 
    pf_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    pf_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    pf_title varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    pf_ppost varchar(1000) NOT NULL, 
    pf_aud varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    pf_username varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    pf_date timestamp  NOT NULL, 
    pf_status  int(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (pf_id) 

    )  ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_reset`
( 
     pr_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     pr_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     pr_email varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
     pr_dob varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     pr_roll varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     pr_date timestamp NOT NULL, 
     pr_status int(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (pr_id) ) ;
```

You also have a wrong key name in the first create statement.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd3e4f/1

Comment: thanks but i still get an error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int(14) NOT NULL, 
   pf_status  int(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (p' at line 8

Comment: @RafedNole, don't like this, I'll Find the right answer, then why did you doing like to hit the answer in this post

Comment: @jmail I dont think U did find the issue of wrong key name !! However for ur knowledge I already upvoted ur answer !! CHeck the my last edit when it was done.

Comment: I agree , but I was stuck in this , SO can't be only for experts sometimes beginners need prodding and thanks

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, then why dare to edit answer of your old answer, you should mention to update and live the old answer..

Comment: Well u have to edit the answer and if I am not wrong u do all the time, leaving some typo which I had where I did not notice there was a space between pf_date timestam !! And I dont need to explain you on that. Perhaps u kinda in reputation war !!

Comment: @RafedNole, Are you beginners for `sql` only not `stackoverflow` you already got the `Reputation of : 382.

Comment: **@AbhikChakraborty, oh, I see `leaving some typo` nice try, you should see the first comment on your wall.**

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the value of length :`timestamp`

```
 pr_date timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
```

like to change:

```
 pr_date timestamp NOT NULL,
```

look like your full code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pforum` 

( 
    pf_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    pf_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    pf_title varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    pf_ppost varchar(1000) NOT NULL, 
    pf_aud varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    pf_username varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    pf_date timestamp  NOT NULL, 
    pf_status  int(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (pf_id) 

    )  ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

---

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_reset`
( 
     pr_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     pr_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     pr_email varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
     pr_dob varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     pr_roll varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     pr_date timestamp NOT NULL, 
     pr_status int(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (pr_id) ) ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: yeah that was wrong format you should reomve these thinks, because the timestamp is showing time and date so, don't give to `length`

Comment: Thanks Also, is it better to use timestamp or datetime ?